# Is it possible to "Bake UV map" to another similar object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have two similar geometry but different topology/faces. Similar to bake textures, where you manipulate a texture to make it compatible with another UV set, can you bake UV maps? So instead of needing to manipulate textures, you make the UV set compatible with the texture.[image: two simlar objects]

Comment: You can data transfer UV.  This is not likely to be perfect however.  Imagine the case of a seam on the source running through the face of the destination-- there's no solution to that.

Comment: ah, data transfer works pretty well! thanks! i couldnt arrive to that with google for some reason.